# How to add show all for sidebar filters in magento2

Tags: magento-2.0

I am trying to add show all filters but i dont know how to add in magento please  see image link i searched for a code but i need to activate this to filters on sidebar in magento2 can anyone help me please for this  please check code i want like that for sidebar filters

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Load the first 3 list items from another HTML file
    //$('#myList').load('externalList.html li:lt(3)');
    $('#myList li:lt(3)').show();
    $('#showLess').hide();
    var items =  25;
    var shown =  3;
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        $('#showLess').show();
        shown = $('#myList li:visible').size()+5;
        if(shown< items) {$('#myList li:lt('+shown+')').show();}
        else {$('#myList li:lt('+items+')').show();
             $('#loadMore').hide();
             }
    });
    $('#showLess').click(function () {
        $('#myList li').not(':lt(3)').hide();
    });
});
```

```css
#myList li{ display:none;
}
#loadMore {
    color:green;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#loadMore:hover {
    color:black;
}
#showLess {
    color:red;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#showLess:hover {
    color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myList">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
    <li>Seven</li>
    <li>Eight</li>
    <li>Nine</li>
    <li>Ten</li>
    <li>Eleven</li>
    <li>Twelve</li>
    <li>Thirteen</li>
    <li>Fourteen</li>
    <li>Fifteen</li>
    <li>Sixteen</li>
    <li>Seventeen</li>
    <li>Eighteen</li>
    <li>Nineteen</li>
    <li>Twenty one</li>
    <li>Twenty two</li>
    <li>Twenty three</li>
    <li>Twenty four</li>
    <li>Twenty five</li>
</ul>
<div id="loadMore">Load more</div>
<div id="showLess">Show less</div>
```

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dr8sH.png)